# How to overwrite billing address in paypal?

Tags: php, paypal, yii2

I am new to Paypal. What I have try till now is

```
  $apiContext = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
  new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(
    'My Client ID',
    'My ClientSecret'
   )
  );

  $addr = new Address();
  $addr->setLine1("3909 Witmer Road")
        ->setLine2("Niagara Falls")
        ->setCity("Niagara Falls")
        ->setState("NY")
        ->setPostalCode("14305")
        ->setCountryCode("US")
        ->setPhone("716-298-1822");

   $$payer_info= new PayerInfo();
   $$payer_info->setBillingAddress($addr);

   $payer = new Payer();
   $payer->setPaymentMethod("paypal")
         ->setPayerInfo($payer_info);

    $itemList = new ItemList();
    $itemList->setItems(array($item1))
          //->setShippingAddress($shipToAddress1);

    $details = new Details();
    $details->setShipping(0)
        ->setTax(0)
        ->setSubtotal($formattedAmount);

    $amount = new Amount();
    $amount->setCurrency('USD');
    $amount->setTotal($formattedAmount);
   $amount->setDetails($details);

$transaction = new Transaction();
$transaction->setAmount($amount)
    ->setItemList($itemList)
    ->setDescription("Payment description")
    ->setInvoiceNumber(uniqid());

//$baseUrl = getBaseUrl();
$redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();

$redirectUrls->setReturnUrl("My return url")
    ->setCancelUrl("My cancel url");

$payment = new Payment();
$payment->setIntent("authorize")
    ->setPayer($payer)
    ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)
    ->setTransactions(array($transaction));

$request = clone $payment;

try {
  $payment->create($apiContext);
  } catch (\PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $ex) {
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r(json_decode($ex->getData()));
  exit(1);
}

$approvalUrl = $payment->getApprovalLink();
return $payment;
```

I want users to choose Paypal or other(ie.visa,mastercard) in Paypal system. Everything seems to be working fine. But the problem are:-

a.If user choose other payment gateway,I cannot per-polluted user form with address which I passed in $addr.

b.If user choose the Paypal login, overwrite the billing address of Paypal which was passed from my web page.

And my question are:-

1.How can I pre-polluted the user form?

2.I am not sure is possible to overwrite the Paypal billing address.If is possible, how can I achive this?

3.If no, can you help me to understand the better solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: when I try to read response before redirect to PayPal.I can see billing address from site but when login to PayPal I see old billing address from PayPal. I try to do same with shipping address                  $shippingAddress = new ShippingAddress(); and $itemList->setShippingAddress($shipToAddress1);                                       is also not overriding.Can anyone suggest me what i did wrong?